# What does this error mean: "got logits shape [3,3] and labels shape [33]"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I created two random arrays in NumPy and then I used `x` and `y` in `model.fit()` but I got this error:

> Node:
> 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
> logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape
> [3,3] and labels shape [33]    [[{{node
> sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_6412]

What does this error mean?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy

x=np.random.randint(40,100,33).reshape(3, 11)
y=np.random.randint(44,66,33).reshape(3, 11)

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
        layers.Dense(3, name="layer3"),
    ]
)
# Call model on a test input

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.0001),loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x,y,batch_size=10,epochs=5,verbose=2)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider multiple steps:

1. The shape of x, y should be equal in the first dimension. you have error here.
2. Read Doc [`numpy.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html). you write `np.random.randint(44,66,33)` so you have `66-44 = 20` different classes for y, but at the last layer, you write  : `layers.Dense(3)`. you have an error here.
3. Add [`layers.Input(shape=(...,))`](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/input/) to your network base shape of `x`.
4. For generating random numbers between `[0,1)` you can use [`numpy.random.rand`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html)

**Try like below:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy

x=np.random.rand(40,100, 3).reshape(40,-1)
y=np.random.randint(0,3, size=40)

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Input(shape=(300,)),
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
        layers.Dense(3, name="layer3"),
    ]
)

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.0001),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x,y,batch_size=10,epochs=2)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/2
4/4 [==============================] - 1s 5ms/step - loss: 5.9796 - accuracy: 0.2500
Epoch 2/2
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 5.9774 - accuracy: 0.2500
```